# Parse Cloud Code Function iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have set up a simple Cloud Code function that should return an array of PFObjects, but it is not.

iOS:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"updateWeekly" withParameters:@{} block:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"objects %@", objects);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
```

Cloud Code (javascript):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateWeekly", function(request, response) {
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var query = new Parse.Query("Future_Events");
  query.ascending("endDate");
  query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("endDate", dateToday);
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    response.success(results);
  },
  error: function() {
    response.error("ERROR!!!???!!!");
  }
  });
});
```

The log in xcode is:

> 2015-09-23 05:14:26.814 LP[30914:4355776] -[__NSDate UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f968159e260
>
> 2015-09-23 05:14:26.825 LP[30914:4355776] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f968159e260'

Ideas for what is wrong?

Comment: UTF8String is a message of NSString and you are calling it on NSDate Object

Comment: where is dateToday declaration?

Comment: it's there, accidentally deleted it here... edited.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, my response of "results" should be an array of PFObjects, not dates, whereby I would not have even touched an NSDate.

Comment: Which line is the crash on, and what is the full stack trace?

Comment: bah... bug... updated SDK... all is good